# Shell script on passing arguments

Tags: shell

My code was like this I'm passing 4 arguments to a script

```
ex.sh "wavpath" "featpath"
```

"ex.sh"
code is

```
#!/bin/bash

wavPath=$1
featPath=$2
rm -f $scpFile

echo $wavPath
echo $featPath


for dir in `ls -R $wavPath|grep ":"|cut -d':' -f1`
do
    mkdir -p ${dir/$wavPath/$featPath}
done
```

The error message:

> bad substitution

and it is at `${dir/$wavPath/$featPath}`
and its showing both the paths

can anyone help

Comment: No need to use shout at us (don't use caps lock). People are less inclined to help you that way.

Answer (score 3):

Try ${dir}/${wavPath}/${featPath}

Answer (score 0):

maybe you meant `$dir/$wavPath/$featPath`

try changing

```
mkdir -p ${dir/$wavPath/$featPath}
```

to

```
echo $dir/$wavPath/$featPath
```

and see if the output is what you expected for the input of `mkdir`.

Also, you're not setting a value for the variable `$scpFile` before you use it.

Comment: ${dir/$wavPath/$featPath} is the problem itself, a variable is in the form ${name}